# MySQL query not looping inside foreach

Tags: php

I have a form which uploads files, but this script should also update the current files if they already exists in the database. This is where it stops. Everything works fine in the script, except from the last if/else if that I will include. It is all in a foreach loop, as there is multiple files that can be uploaded. It is after the "move_uploaded_file" it fails.

It uploads all the files, but only uploads one of the rows in database, and also ignore adding more.

I've never tried such an approach before, so I have tried to search a while for an answer, but cannot find what I need. I am probably missing something obvious..

```
foreach ($_FILES['ufile']['name'] as $f => $name) 

switch ($f) {
    case '0':
        $type = '1';
        break;
    case '1':
        $type = '2';
        break;
    case '2':
        $type = '3';
        break;
    case '3':
        $type = '4';
        break;
    default:
        $type = false;
        break;
}


    $allowedExts = array(
      'pdf', 
      'doc', 
      'docx'
    );

    $extension = end(explode(".", $name));

    if ($_FILES['ufile']['error'][$f] == 4) {
        continue; // Skip file if any error found
    }          
    if ($_FILES['ufile']['error'][$f] == 0) {
        if ($_FILES['ufile']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
            $errors[] = "Some errormessage.";
            continue; // Skip large files
        }
        elseif(!in_array($extension, $allowedExts )){
            $errors[] = "Some errormessage.";
            continue; // Skip invalid file formats
        }
        elseif($type == false){
            $errors[] = "Some errormessage.";
            continue; // Skip invalid file formats
        }
        else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files 
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["ufile"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$name))
            $qGetFil = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM moter_filer WHERE mote_id=?");
            $qGetFil->bind_param('s', $_GET['id']);
            $qGetFil->execute();
            $rGetResults = $qGetFil->get_result();

            $rGetFil = $rGetResults->fetch_assoc();
            $rGetNewRow = $rGetResults->num_rows;

            if($rGetNewRow > '0' && $type == $rGetFil['type']){
                unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/filer/' . $rGetFil['fil']);
                $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE moter_filer SET fil= ? WHERE mote_id= ? AND type= ?");
                $stmt->bind_param('sss', $name, $_GET['id'], $type);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->close();
            }elseif($rGetNewRow == '0'){
                $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO moter_filer(type,mote_id, fil) VALUES (?,?,?)");
                $stmt->bind_param('sss', $type, $_GET['id'], $name);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->close();
            }

            $success[] = "Some sccessmessage.";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And now let's guess what error you are having

Comment: First, find out what exactly the following command states: `echo $mysqli->error` Second, your code is absolutely unsafe. Please change to using parametrized queries.

Comment: @Alexander , I updated my code now.
There are no mysql errors present.

Comment: @BeastMode Mysql errors don't just appear out of nowhere, you have to print them out ya-self when something fails.

Comment: @Jonast92 I did echo the $mysqli->error, and I still have them active in my live code, but there is nothing present.

Answer (score 0):

I this line:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["ufile"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path.$name))
```

Ther is no curly braces, so the query is executed only if  move_upload_file returns true.
 Problem is that the rest of the lines are executed even if move_upload_file fails
because they are out of the if condition:

```
 $rGetFil = $qGetFil->fetch_array();     
 $rGetNewRow = $qGetFiler->num_rows;
```

You are also reading extension from filename instead of using the mime type "type" value inside:

```
$_FILES['ufile']['type'][$f]
```

Comment: I updated the code a little.
I still have the same problem, with no errors present. The queries are supposed to run only when a file is actually uploaded, but it looks like it won't loop the queries. As for the extension, the form is private and not public, so I figured I don't need a more complex validation until I at least figure out the main problem. :-)